# print a group of the first consecutive lines matching a regex then exit

Tags: regex, logging, sed, grep

I would like to print the lines in a log file filtered by current time.

The setup I have right now reads the entire file and prints only the lines that match.
How should I stop sed from reading the entire file while still printing the multiple lines.

Normally the lines I need are 3 lines deep into the log and multiple lines long.

Currently I use:

```
timestamp=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
tac mylogfile | gsed -n "/^$timestamp/p" | tac
```

tac is a bit superfluous in this simple demo

Example data:

```
2013-08-19 19:23:42
2013-08-19 19:23:42
2013-08-19 19:23:42
2013-08-19 19:23:42
2013-08-19 19:23:43
2013-08-19 19:23:43
2013-08-19 19:23:43
2013-08-19 19:23:44
2013-08-19 19:23:44
2013-08-19 19:23:44
2013-08-19 19:23:44
2013-08-19 19:23:45
2013-08-19 19:23:45
2013-08-19 19:23:45
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
2013-08-19 19:23:46
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else, just use awk:

```
awk -v ts="$timestamp" '$0 ~ ts{print; f=1; next} f{exit}' file
```

Comment: I knew there was an awk solution! I haven't gotten much into awk so my first hammer is sed. "If you only have a hammer, you tend to see every problem as a nail." --Abraham Maslow

Comment: You should learn awk. sed is great for the simple stuff but for anything more complicated than `s/foo/bar/g` you should use awk.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Quit Command

You can use the (q)uit command to tell sed when to stop processing and exit. It will still need to process from the start of each file, but can exit whenever the stop pattern is encountered. For example:

```
timestamp_start='2013-08-19 19:23:45'
timestamp_stop='2013-08-19 19:23:46'

sed -n "/$timestamp_start/p; /$timestamp_stop/q" /tmp/example.log
```

If your sed doesn't handle regular expressions for addresses, this won't work for you. I haven't tested it with anything but GNU sed 4.2.2, where it works as described. YMMV.

Comment: All seds handle regular expressions for addresses. It's wanting sed to do anything else, that's usually a problem (e.g. use a string instead).

Comment: I cannot know the timestamp_stop beforehand. As there could be gaps in logging of multiple seconds to even hours.

Answer (score 0):

## My own naive approach

uses labels and conditional branching from 's///; t' to decide to loop or exit.

sed -n "b main; :branch {s/^$timestamp/$timestamp/p; n; t branch; q}; b end; :main /^$timestamp/b branch :end"